# Protection not considering Association Bonus

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-posts, association

I'm not a very active member of SuperUser, but I have more than 100 reputation points because of the Association Bonus.

I'm experiencing something weird... I want to answer a question that's been protected against users with less than 10 reps, but I'm not actually allowed to answer, even though my rep points should be enough.

Is it normal that the 100 rep points coming from my Association Bonus are ignored in regard of protected questions, or is it a bug?

Comment: Just for reference, can you give us a link to the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. The idea is that a user is not considered to have enough experience with the topic of the site, so only rep earned on the site is counted: [Why is the Association Bonus ignored when trying to answer a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question)

Part of the boilerplate includes:

> To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

See also: [Improve "Protected Question" message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati)

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with that stance, since I believe protected questions are more to prevent spam, and a user already experienced with SE in general is unlikely to spam.